# Can I get any info of the owner of the bitcoin wallet?

Tags: wallet

I transferred an amount by the Moonpay site to the person who didn't do what I paid him for.

Moonpay.com page advises me to go to the police and share with them all the information I have about the scammer. Can I get any info of the owner of the bitcoin wallet?

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot get any information about the identity of the recipient just from the Bitcoin address of the recipient.

Privacy was important to the inventor of Bitcoin and they made it difficult to trace participants in a transaction from just the information in a Bitcoin transaction.

If the recipient used a "custodial wallet" - an account with a business, rather than a normal "non-custodial" personally managed wallet, then some people claim to be able, in some cases, to identify the business who provided the account. But that business has a duty to protect the personal details of their customer. To get information from them might take a court order from a court in a foreign country.

---

Similar questions:

- Tracing

  - [Find recipient of a bitcoin transaction?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/65637/13866)
  - [Can I Find out where I sent my bitcoin from my paxful wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/99433/13866)
  - [Can bitcoins be traced to scammers](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/83197/13866)
  - [How is blockchain not responsible for someone stealing my Bitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/105719/13866)
  - [Trace and contact bitcoin thief](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/18849/13866)
  - [Trace Bitcoin Fund Flows When There Are Multiple Input and Output Addresses](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/108330/13866)
- Recovery

  - [How do I recover from a cryptocurrency scam?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91943/13866)
  - [Is there a 'BTC Refund Department'?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/100096/13866)